# Given $f: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x) = \infty = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$, show $f$ attains its minimum.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification, extreme-value-theorem

There are plenty of questions on stack exchange similar to this but my question comes in a minute detail. My attempt: Let $a\in \mathbf{R}$ so that there are $c_1$, $c_2 \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $(c_1, \infty)\cap \mathbf{R} \neq \emptyset$ and $(-\infty, c_2)\cap \mathbf{R} \neq \emptyset$ and $f(t) \in (f(a), \infty)$ whenever $t\in (-\infty, c_2)\cup (c_1, \infty)$. Obviously, there's a standard extreme value argument if $c_2 <c_1$ but if $c_2\geq c_1$ then I come to the statement $$f(t) \in (f(a), \infty)$$ for each $t\in \mathbf{R}$. But this can not be true since $f(a) \notin (f(a), \infty)$ while $a\in \mathbf{R}$. Am I miss applying a definition somewhere?

Comment: The answer is very simple. Your contradiction shows that we *must* have $c_2<c_1$ (which is good!).

Comment: @TedShifrin that is good, but why must we have that? Where is the contradiction? Is the contradiction in the statement that I had a problem with initially?

Comment: Any function attains its minimum. Did you mean "infimum"?

Comment: The contradiction is that $f(t)>f(a)$ for all t.

Comment: I suggest a simpler approach.  Let $a=f(0)$.  Because of limit condition, there is $c$ with $-\infty \lt c \lt 0$ where $f(x)\gt a$ for $-\infty \lt x \lt c$.  Similarly get $d\gt 0$.  Minimum in $(c,d)$ interval.

Comment: @TedShifrin yup! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

The intuition is clear: Outside a compact interval $[-M,M]$ the function $f$ can be as large as you want. So the minimum of $f$ has to be inside the compact interval $[-M,M]$. Now use the fact that a continuous function achieves its minimum over a compact interval.

Comment: To make this intuition rigorous, you just need to take $M$ such that $f(x) > \min_{z\in [-M,M]} f(z)$ for all $|x| > M$.

Comment: I don’t see how this is true in general. We have to have specific numbers in mind for your $M$. If $$f(x) =(x-100)^2-100$$ then $f$ does *not* attain its minimum on $[-M, M]$ where $M=99$.

Comment: My previous comment has already answered your question:  take $M$ such that $f(x)>\min_{z \in [−M,M]} f(z)$ for all $|x|>M$. Such a $M$ exists due to the condition that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $|x| \to \infty$